# User interface in python django

Tags: python, django

I new to Python and Django, i am trying to create a user interface using django for the calculation of the speed (speed= distance/time). I have created a project using django in that i have created a weapp called speed. The below are my files

> Webapp
>
> - speed
>
>   -Templates
>
>   -views.py
>
>   -forms.py
>
>   -urls.py
> - webapp
>
>   -settings.py
>
>   -urls.py
>
>   -init.py
>
>   -wsgi.py

My codes:
    forms.py

```
from django import forms

class Calculatespeed(forms.Form):
    distance=forms.CharField(
        required=True,max_length=10,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"0.0",
                                      "style":"width:100px"}))
    time=forms.CharField(
        required=True,max_length=10,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"0.0",
                                      "style":"width:100px"}))
```

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import template
from speed.forms import Calculatespeed

def speed(Speed):
    distance=float(raw_input("Please Give the disance"))
    Time=float(raw_input("Please Give the Time"))
    Speed=distance/Time
    return Speed

def Main(request):
    if request.GET:
        form = speed_form.SpeedForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            Distance = form.cleaned_data["distance"]
            Time = form.cleaned_data["time"]

    return shortcuts.render_response(
        "speed.html",
        page_context,
        context_instance=template.RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Templates:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WebApp1</title>
</head>
<h1>Speed Calculator</h1>
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
<br>
Distance:
<input type="interger" distance="Distance" />
<br>
Time:
<input type="interger" Time="Time" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from speed.views import speed

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', speed),
)
```

The problem is when i am trying run server i am getting an error i am unable to get the user interface of speed can any one help me on this.

Is the templates files and all the other files which i gave are correct or not ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you planning to keep your data? Do you have any data model?

Comment: show a piece of your data model, and what's the error message

Comment: An error?What is the error message?

Comment: I am suing sqlite3 as a database for that. I don't want to store my data. What all i want to do is like if i give distance and time in the text box. it should display the calculated speed.

Comment: Error Message is: when i am trying to do manage.py runserver in the command prompt its is asking to provide distance in the command prompt itself ( i gave it in command prompt) and then it is asking for providing  time ( i gave it ) after that it is returning a 404 error.

Comment: Don't feel offended, but "what a mess" :P there is no "main" magic in django, each view must be tied to a url, that's how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using raw_input in your view to ask data wanted. I think you didn't understand what a web app is :-) (Or the `speed` function is just for tests, so in that case it would be placed in the `tests.py` of the application)

In your view `main(request)`, you should init a form and if a request POST (can be check with `request.method`) is sent, check if the form is valid.

Here some code which might working (I replace the `render_to_response` by `render` to not confusing you with the context that you misused)

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def speed(distance, time_):  # don't like to name a var time because of the module with the same name...     
    return distance/ time_


def compute_speed(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Calculatespeed(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             distance = form.cleaned_data["distance"]
             time_ = form.cleaned_data["time"]
             speed = speed(distance, time_)
             # Do your stuff here
    else:
        form = Calculatespeed()


    return render(request, "speed.html", {'form': form})
```

And in the `urls.py`:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
                        url(r'^$', compute_speed, name="compute_speed"),
                       )
```

You have also some typos in your HTML:

1. The inte **r** ger input type doesn't exists
2. Why action="/contact/" instead of `{% url 'compute_speed' %}` ?
3. Your form isn't closed

Comment: Hi, I have tried the query given by it is showing the error saying as Attribute Error: Str object has no attribute 'META' what's wrong here

Comment: I forget the first parameter of the render function which is request. I've updated my code

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code, so it seems to me like a very basic misunderstanding of working with django, and maybe with python in general. there are a lot of pythonic errors in your code (you have wrong indentation, you did a 'return' without a function, and so on), and a lot of django-ic errors too (you can't use raw_input in django it doesn't work that way, you created a form but then wrote the entire html yourself).

I suggest that before you write it in django, write this as a python program and see if it works. When you feel like you understand the language enough and want to web-app your program, go over the django docs and take some time to [learn how it works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).